# FindFirstChagneNotification cannot find specified file

Tags: c++, windows, file-monitoring

I've searched and cannot find any answers on this.  I'm trying to create a file monitoring program in C++ on Windows. The FindFirstChangeNotification function always fails to find the specified file. I've even tried hard coding the path for testing.
Sample code is

```
LPTSTR lpDir = (LPTSTR)("C:\\Users\\userName\\Desktop");
HANDLE dwChangeHandle;

dwChangeHandle = FindFirstChangeNotification(
    lpDir,  // directory to watch
    FALSE,  // Don't watch subtree
    FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE);

if (dwChangeHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
    ExitProcess(GetLastError());
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cast of the path looks iffy - if you compile for Unicode it won't find the path, as you're not actually pointing to the correct type of string.

You should do `LPTSTR lpDir = TEXT("C:\\Users\\userName\\Desktop");`

Comment: Just use the UTF-16 wide version... much fewer issues... and less preprocessor garbage